# SQLite DB for GWT?

Tags: java, sqlite, html, gwt

I'm trying to create a Packaged App for Chrome using GWT, I need an SQLite DB. I can't seem to find any decent resources on doing this. I've looked at gwt-mobile-webkit, is that the definitive way to use sqlite in gwt? I'm getting errors when I follow their example, it seems it hasn't been updated in awhile. Based on the lack of results I'm thinking I'm not searching for the right thing, any guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd check out [gwt-mobile-webkit](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mobile-webkit/), or more specifically the [Database API](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mobile-webkit/wiki/DatabaseApi). Though the name says "mobile", it definitely works on the desktop. This library wraps the HTML5 database support, which (depending on the browser) is either SQLite or [IndexedDB](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/). There are plenty of other, heavier weight wrappers, but this is the best and easiest I've seen around.

Comment: There is nothing there, am I missing something?

Comment: Edited answer to provide more. Sorry for the confusion.