# How to use SQLite with GWT?

Tags: java, sqlite, gwt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQLite DB for GWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237612/sqlite-db-for-gwt)

I know how to use SQLite with Android applications but I can't seem to figure out how to get started using SQLite with GWT for use in building a Packaged App for Chrome. What do I need? I've been searching for days and found nothing, so I think I'm off track. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check out [gwt-jdbc-html5](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-jdbc-html5/), since HTML5 now provides built-in SQLite support. There are plenty of other, heavier weight wrappers, but this is the best and easiest I've seen around.